# perl-5.14.2 make test failed

Tags: perl, ubuntu, makefile

I am trying to install perl-5.14.2 from source on Ubuntu 20. The steps to follow are:

```
cd perl-5.14.2
./Configure -des -Dprefix=$HOME/localperl
make
make test
make install
```

However, on doing make test, the compilation fails with the following error:

> ext/Errno/t/Errno..............................................FAILED--Further testing stopped: No errno's are exported
> make: *** [makefile:854: test] Error 29

The gcc version on the system is 9.3.0.

Comment: Can you try using [`patchperl`](https://metacpan.org/pod/Devel::PatchPerl) ? See [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/65594391/2173773) answer

Comment: I did, and it solved most of the issues but failed at h2ph: lib/h2ph.......................................................# Failed at ../lib/h2ph.t line 49

Comment: I tried now to install 5.14.4 (not 5.14.2) on Ubuntu 21.04, and all the the tests passed (after having run patchperl). Maybe you could try to install 5.14.4 instead of 5.14.2 ? You can download it from here: https://www.cpan.org/src/5.0/perl-5.14.4.tar.bz2

Comment: Not working with this either, shows the same error. Kindly help me out.

Comment: Can you update your question with more information about the error? (The output produced by `make test`)

Comment: Here is the output of make test:  
lib/Getopt/Std.................................................ok
lib/h2ph.......................................................# Failed at ../lib/h2ph.t line 49
# got 'Illegal declaration of subroutine main::__has_include at _h2ph_pre.ph line 689.
# '
# expected /(?^:syntax OK$)/
# Failed at ../lib/h2ph.t line 56
#      got "Illegal character in prototype for main::__has_include : STR at _h2ph_pre.ph line 689.\nCompilation failed in require at lib/h2ph.pht line 1.\nCompilation failed in require at -e line 1.\n"
# expected ""
FAILED at test 5

Comment: Can you try apply the patch given by @azrle in [this](https://github.com/bingos/devel-patchperl/issues/23) issue?

Comment: I am a newbie with patches, could you guide me in applying the patch?